# Making mobile view set at a specific width using viewport

Tags: html, css, viewport

have been looking around for a solution to my query but haven't had any luck.

I have a website that I have designed with css responsive design.

I wanted to know if there is a way to use viewport to make a device such as an ipad
view the website look like that of a larger width device.

Essentially I want to make these responsive elements now sit like they do on a desktop computer but on an ipad and other mobile devices.

Have tried things such as
    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1>` but no luck so far.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width="1100">` seems to make all the content appear the way I want but aligns the site to the left not centred.

I've used @media queries for my css and now I want mobile devices to essentially ignore these responsive design elements and look like it does in a desktop browser.

Any help appreiated

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, put this in your css.

```
<style>
@media ( max-width:110px) {
.yourmenu{
 //do your css coding here, you may tweak the size

 }
}
</style>
```

more here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not what I'm after, I've used @media queries for my css and now I want mobile devices to essentially ignore these responsive design and look like it does in a desktop browser.

Comment: is creating another separate page not an option?

Comment: a seperate page for what exactly?

The website is layed out as I want it and using `<meta name="viewport" content="width="1100">` lays my website out on mobile devices exactly how I want it but pushes the whole site (which sits in the centre it is not a full width site) to the left with a margin only on the right